# Pattern Matching with Varying types of Tuples

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to figure out how to pattern match with user defined types. For example I have this type.

```
Type custom_type = B of bool | I of int | S of string | C of custom_type * custom_type
```

I want to pattern match these types, and say for example count the number of ints in a value. Example value:

```
C(C(B true, I 5), C(S "example", B false))
```

I think I'm very close to figuring it out, I know I need to use wildcards but I can't write out every instance there could be, because there are numerous varying values I need to check.

Thanks!

Edit: Code that isn't working:

```
let num = 0
let rec count_ints (c: custom_type):int =
match c with
| C (I(_), _) -> num + 1
| C (_, I(_)) -> num + 1
| C (C(_), _) -> count_ints c
| C (_, C(_)) -> count_ints c
```

Comment: There seem like a lot of things to check, but there are really only  4 different cases. For the `C` case you can call your function recursively to handle the inner cases. If you want more specific commentary, show some code that isn't working, and explain what's not working about it.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, here's what I've got so far. I don't know if I'm using recursion properly.

Comment: Just as a hint: you don't need to match what's inside your `C` constructor. Call yourself recursively to handle the contents. Also don't forget to handle the other 3 constructors in your match.

Answer (score 0):

You should be thinking of having 4 cases in your function, one for each constructor. You don't need to match what's inside these constructors because you can call yourself recursively to handle that.

Your code calls `count_chars`, but there's no function of that name. If it's supposed to be `count_ints`, then this is not a good recursive call. You *must* call recursively on a smaller problem. If you just pass `c` along to yourself recursively you'll get infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
let rec count_ints (c: custom_type):int = 
    match c with 
    | I _ -> 1 
    | C (c1,c2) -> count_ints c1 + count_ints c2 
    | _ -> 0
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.